# Rerun CPAN Config on Linux?

Tags: perl, cpan

I accidentally interrupted CPAN while it was doing the initial configuration and now I cannot start it again.

I am receiving the error

```
Error while requiring CPAN::MyConfig: CPAN/MyConfig.pm did not return a true value at /usr/share/perl/5.14/CPAN/HandleConfig.pm line 507
```

Is there any way to rerun the config if I can't even open the cpan shell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the file `CPAN/MyConfig.pm` (or, better, move it somewhere; you might want to look at it).

Then try again.

Comment: that file is probably in `~/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm` (for \*NIX and MacOSX -- I dunno about Win\*)

Answer (score 4):

As Jonathan said, moving that file out of the way will let you continue. Though better would be to use "cpan minus": http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-cpanminus/lib/App/cpanminus.pm

It is much faster and simpler to use and has lots of amazing features.

https://github.com/miyagawa/cpanminus

Comment: Or [CPANPLUS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CPANPLUS). It is another reworking of CPAN.